# Problem casting STL complex<double> to fftw_complex

Tags: c++, fftw, complex-numbers, reinterpret-cast

The FFTW manual [says](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Complex-numbers.html#Complex-numbers) that its `fftw_complex` type is bit compatible to `std::complex<double>` class in STL. But that doesn't work for me:

```
#include <complex>
#include <fftw3.h>
int main()
{
   std::complex<double> x(1,0);
   fftw_complex fx;
   fx = reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex>(x);
}
```

This gives me an error:

```
error: invalid cast from type ‘std::complex<double>’ to type ‘double [2]’
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Re-write your code as follows:

```
#include <complex>
#include <fftw3.h>
int main()
{
   std::complex<double> x(1,0);
   fftw_complex fx;
   memcpy( &fx, &x, sizeof( fftw_complex ) );
}
```

Every compiler I've used will optimise out the memcpy because it is copying a fixed, ie at compile time, amount of data.

This avoids [pointer aliasing issues](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html).

**Edit:** You can also avoid strict aliasing issues using a union as follows:

```
#include <complex>
#include <fftw3.h>
int main()
{
   union stdfftw
   {
       std::complex< double > stdc;
       fftw_complex           fftw;
   };
   std::complex<double> x(1,0);
   stdfftw u;
   u.stdc = x;
   fftw_complex fx = u.fftw;
}
```

Though strictly this C99 rules (Not sure about C++) are broken as reading from a different member of a union to the one written too is undefined.  It works on most compilers though.  Personally I prefer my original method.

Comment: Ok, that works for me! 3 years not coding in pure C :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: @galadog
Is the memcpy necessary? Why couldn't you do this: 

`std::complex<double> x(1,0); fftw_complex* fx = &x`

Comment: what about with an array of complex numbers?

Answer (score 23):

The idea behind bit-compatibility of fftw_complex and C99 and C++ complex types is not that they can be easily created from one another, but that all functions in FFTW that take pointers to fftw_complex can also take pointers to c++ std::complex. Therefore the best approach is probably to use std::complex<> throughout your program and only convert pointers to these values when calling FFTW functions:

```
std::vector<std::complex<double> > a1, a2;
....
....
fftw_plan_dft(N, reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(&a1[0]),
                 reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(&a2[0]),
                 FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
....
```

Comment: By far the best way to go.

Answer (score 7):

`reinterpret_cast` only works for pointers and references. So you'd have to do this:

```
#include <complex>
#include <fftw3.h>
int main()
{
   std::complex<double> x(1,0);
   fftw_complex fx(*reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(&x));
}
```

This assumes that `fftw_complex` has a copy constructor. To avoid problems with strict aliasing, [Goz's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214400/problem-casting-stl-complexdouble-to-fftw-complex/4214426#4214426) should be preferred.

Comment: What you do above breaks strict aliasing rules and should be avoided.  GCC will warn you for doing it and will potentially break if you have strict aliasing turned on.

Comment: @Goz: You are right. I added a warning and referred to your answer.

Comment: Works for references too: `fftw_complex fx(reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex&>(x));`