# Converting from complex<double>* to fftw_complex*

Tags: visual-c++, fftw

I have an input `complex<double>* g (2D-array)`.

In order to fourier transform it I first convert it

`in=(fftw_complex*)g;`

Where `in` is the input for `fftw`.

After performing the fft, the code

```
fftw_free(out);
fftw_free(in);
```

doesnt work.

I get an "unhandled exception" error.

I'm afraid the problem is with the conversion. any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is a discussion on casting STL complex to and from fftw_complex here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4214400/1328439.

Comment: I didn't miss it. But they are talking about converting complex<double> and not complex<double>*.

Comment: BTW, when trying the to work with the solution offered in the link you suggested, The problem remains basically the same. This time I define an array temp of type fftw_complex* and use memcpy to to copy the data to temp, so noe free works on the input and output of the fft (in and out) but fftw_free(temp) gives  "unhandled exception" error again... so the problem is just displaced...

Comment: What happens if you "manually" copy the data from _g_ to _in_? Are you still able to perform the _fftw_free()_ operations? Also, it might be worthwhile sharing the "performing the fft" part of your code. You might be doing something in there that you didn't think would cause trouble. Or you could just try a _fftw_free()_ immediately after recasting to see if its really the re-casting that's causing the problem.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce this problem with the *very* limited information in the question but am unable to. The error is most likely in code that is not shown. Its not clear whether `fftw_free(out);` causes the exception or `fftw_free(in);`. If its `fftw_free(out);` then it most likely isn't the conversion that is the issue. How do you allocate `g`? What do you do in between the conversion and freeing of `in`? Do you deallocate `g` after converting it?