# std::copy() vs memcpy() with std::vectors and fftw_malloc

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, memcpy

I know when dealing with `std::vector`, it's best to use `std::copy()`, however I was wondering how to copy an `fftw_malloc` array into a `std::vector`? Should I use `std::copy()` or `memcpy()`?

Example code:

```
static const int nx = 8;
static const int ny = 8;
static const int nyk = ny/2 + 1;
static const int Mx = 3*nx/2, My= 3*ny/2;

double M[2] = {Mx,My};

fftw_complex *array1;
array1= (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(nx*nyk* sizeof(fftw_complex)); 
memset(array1, 42, nx*nyk* sizeof(fftw_complex));

std::vector<std::complex<double>> array2(Mx*My,0.0); 

std::copy( array1, array1+(nx*nyk) , array2); //std::copy( src, src + size, dest );
```

I am trying to copy `array1` into `array2`, where `array2 > array1`, then would like to use `std::vector` operators to append values, and so on.

This doesn't really work, and I am not sure if my `vector` syntax is off, or `std::copy()` is not the way to go. Should I use `memcpy()` instead?

Comment: did you  try `array2.data()` instead of `array2` in the `std::copy` line?

Comment: is `fftw_complex` assignable to `std::complex<double>`?

Comment: @doug Yes and I get the error ``error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::complex<double
’ and ‘double [2]’)``

Comment: @Quimby I am not sure really

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214400/problem-casting-stl-complexdouble-to-fftw-complex) claims they are equal bitwise so both `std::copy` or `memcpy` into `array2.data()` should work.

Comment: But [cpprefernce](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) talks about arrays compiler-depending implementation.

Comment: Try `reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double>*>(array2.data())` The standard requires the real and imaginary parts are in [0] and [1] respectively.

Comment: @doug Yeah I think this works with no errors for me, thanks

Comment: @Ripi2 It's fine. `std::complex<double>` can be defined differently in different compilers but `reinterpret_cast<double*>(&my_complex)[0]` and `reinterpret_cast<double*>(&my_complex)[1]` is defined to access the real and imaginary parts C style (like doug showed, but the other way around is defined too).

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, adding a `ftww_complex` one by one to a vector with the help of `reinterpret_cas` is good. The point is how to add a full array of `fftw_complex` with a direct command.

Comment: @Ripi2 It's no different if you have one or many. Underneath, there's only a long row of `double`s. real, img, real, img, real, img ...

Comment: @Jamie Are any of the sizes of your arrays/vectors runtime values or are they `constexpr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These days, it doesn't make a lot of difference to use `fftw_malloc` vs. using regularly allocated memory for FFTW operations (see timing results at the end).

Having said that,
the problem in your code is two-fold.
First, the last argument of `std::copy` needs to be an iterator (e.g. `array2.begin()`).
Second, the value type is incompatible; you are transforming `fftw_complex` into `std::complex<double>`, which are different types (albeit they have the same bitwise representation).

So you have several options:

```
std::copy( reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double>*>(array1), reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double>*>(array1+(nx*nyk)) , array2.begin());
```

Which, in turn, can be simplified to

```
std::copy_n( reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double>*>(array1), nx*nyk, array2.begin());
```

If you don't like to `reinterpret_cast` you can transform the data.

```
std::transform( array1, array1 + nx*nyk, array2.begin(), [](auto const& z) {return std::complex<double>(z[0], z[1])});
```

(there is no `std::transform_n`).

You can skip the two-step process:

```
std::vector<std::complex<double>> array2(reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double>*>(array1), reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double>*>(array1+(nx*nyk)));
```

---

Honestly, I would try to make everything work with normal allocation.
Besides, what do you gain by allocating with `fftw_malloc` to copy immediately to a regular `std::vector`, possibly losing the alignment properties?
(I hope you are trying to copy to the vector after the FFTW operation.)

The most elegant solution is to have an FFTW-aware allocator altogether.
https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/blob/master/include/multi/adaptors/fftw/memory.hpp?ref_type=heads#L27

```
using Z = std::complex<double>;
std::vector<Z, multi::fftw::allocator<Z>> array2(...);
```

In this way, you don't have to manage any memory and have the benefits of FFTW allocation, if any.

---

Finally, `std::vector` is not even the best container to hold data subject to FFT operation;
if nothing else, because most interesting FFTs are multidimensional.

In my array library, FFTW is adapted and can be used in this way:

```
#include <multi/adaptors/fftw.hpp>
#include <multi/array.hpp>

namespace multi = boost::multi;  // from https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi

int main() {
  multi::array<std::complex<double>, 2, multi::fftw::allocator<> > in({Mx, My});
  ...
  multi::array<std::complex<double>, 2, multi::fftw::allocator<> > out({Mx, My});
  multi::fftw::dft_forward({true, true}, in, out);
  ...
}
```

(code in this answer is not tested)

---

Timing results, fftw_malloc vs normal allocation:

I measured, and I don't see any benefit in using `fftw_malloc` vs. `new/std::allocator`.

https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/blob/master/include/multi/adaptors/fftw/benchmark/memory.cpp?ref_type=heads#L94

These tests are for 1D and 2D data, run in a Intel® Core™ i7-9750H × 12 (48GB), running in Ubuntu 23.04 with FFTW version `libfftw3-mpi3/lunar 3.3.10-1ubuntu1 amd64` and g++ 13 with `-O3 -DNDEBUG`.

[image: benchmark]

Comment: That allocator... Lovely! That way one can just wrap a `std::vector<std::complex<double>, multi::fftw::allocator<std::complex<double>>>` in a class instead of keeping the raw pointers internally and provide cast functions to `fftw_complex*` when interacting with `fftw` functions.

Comment: Or use `multi::fftw` adaptor ;) (see my edit). It even has a "functional" interface that allows `out = multi::fftw::dft_forward(in);` with no unnecessary allocations.

Comment: Jeez... I wish I could upvote `multi`ple times! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Background: The standard makes it defined to `reinterpret_cast<double*>` from a `std::complex<double>*` and vice versa. The memory layout of a `std::complex<double>` is guaranteed to be that of two adjacent `double`s in memory. Internally, it could be something like any of these:

```
template<class T>
struct complex1 {
    T m_real;
    T m_img;
};
//---
template<class T>
struct complex2 {
    T m_data[2];
};
//---
template<class T> struct complex3;

template<>
struct complex3<double> {
    double _Complex m_data; // The C complex type
};
```

`std:complex<T>` is one of the few (maybe only?) class where you have this guarantee that it's ok to `reinterpret_cast` a pointer to it and view it as-if through a pointer to another type, back and forth.

---

However, working with these different types isn't nice and clutters the code with `reinterpret_cast`s so I would start by writing a wrapper, let's call it `ComplexArray`, around the raw pointers that's returned by `fftw_malloc` - and I'd use `fftw_alloc_complex` instead of the more generic `fftw_malloc`. The wrapper should give you as a C++ programmer the possibility of working with the data so that it can be used with the algorithms in the standard libary of C++.

I'd still use the `fftw` allocation functions instead of just going for a `std::vector<std::complex<double>>` directly (which is perfectly fine) because they *"guarantee that the returned pointer obeys any special alignment restrictions imposed by any algorithm in FFTW (e.g. for SIMD acceleration)"*.

By providing this wrapper with iterator support, copying the data into a `std::vector<std::complex<double>>` becomes just as easy as when working with any C++ container. You can even create the `vector` directly from your wrapper's iterators.

The target would be the possibility to write your `main` function like this:

```cpp
int main() {
    static const int nx = 8;
    static const int ny = 8;
    static const int nyk = ny / 2 + 1;
    static const int Mx = 3 * nx / 2, My = 3 * ny / 2;

    ComplexArray array1(nx * nyk); // the new C++ container

    // no more memset(..., 42, ...), use real C++ std::complex<double>s:
    array1.fill(std::complex<double>{1.4260258159703532e-105,
                                     1.4260258159703532e-105});

    // create a vector from your ComplexArray
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> array2(array1.begin(), array1.end());
}
```

An example implementation of `ComplexArray` could look like this and will work as a substitute for `std::vector<std::complex<double>>` in most situations you want when working with `fftw` so you may not even need to copy it to a `vector` and you can add copying and creating it from iterators and other useful things if you need. This is a start:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <complex>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>

class ComplexArray {
public:
    using value_type = std::complex<double>;

    using pointer = value_type*;
    using const_pointer = const value_type*;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using const_reference = const value_type&;

    using iterator = value_type*;
    using const_iterator = const value_type*;
    using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
    using reverse_const_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;

    ComplexArray() = default;
    ComplexArray(std::size_t size) : m_data(fftw_alloc_complex(size)) {}

    // move semantics comes for free, copying does not:
    ComplexArray(ComplexArray&&) = default;
    ComplexArray& operator=(ComplexArray&&) = default;

    // misc ...
    std::size_t size() const { return m_size; }
    void fill(const std::complex<double>& val) { std::fill(begin(), end(), val); }

    // access
    const_pointer data() const {
        return reinterpret_cast<const_pointer>(m_data.get());
    }
    pointer data() { return reinterpret_cast<pointer>(m_data.get()); }

    const_reference operator[](std::size_t idx) const { return data()[idx]; }
    reference operator[](std::size_t idx) { return data()[idx]; }

    // functions to provide fftw functions direct access to the data
    const fftw_complex* fftw_data() const { return m_data.get(); }
    fftw_complex* fftw_data() { return m_data.get(); }

    // iterators ...
    const_iterator cbegin() const { return data(); }
    const_iterator cend() const { return data() + m_size * sizeof(value_type); }
    const_iterator begin() const { return cbegin(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return cend(); }
    iterator begin() { return data(); }
    iterator end() { return data() + m_size * sizeof(value_type); }

    // reverse iterators ...
    reverse_const_iterator crbegin() const {
        return reverse_const_iterator(cend());
    }
    reverse_const_iterator crend() const {
        return reverse_const_iterator(cbegin());
    }
    reverse_const_iterator rbegin() const { return crbegin(); }
    reverse_const_iterator rend() const { return crend(); }
    reverse_iterator rbegin() { return reverse_iterator(end()); }
    reverse_iterator rend() { return reverse_iterator(begin()); }

private:
    struct fftw_freer {
        void operator()(fftw_complex* cplx) const noexcept { fftw_free(cplx); }
    };
    std::unique_ptr<fftw_complex, fftw_freer> m_data;
    std::size_t m_size = 0;
};
```

Comment: If we are going to change the container all together, it is simpler to just write a custom allocator https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/blob/master/include/multi/adaptors/fftw/memory.hpp?ref_type=heads#L27 , and keep using the same container template (although `std::vector` is not even the best container to hold data subject to FFT transformations, if nothing else because most interesting FFTs are multidimensional, including the one in the question). But it is a matter of taste.

Comment: @alfC Yes, I just noticed your answer and looked at the allocator. Very nice!

Comment: In case you are interested, I finally decided to test, and I found no difference using fftw_malloc or regular allocation. In current architectures, memory is probably always aligned well for FFTW operations. (See my edit). So one shouldn't bother too much about using `fftw_malloc` these days.

Comment: @alfC I've done `-mnative` comparisons where I've manually over-aligned memory, but I haven't seem to find a sweetspot for my old Xeon. Perhaps I should redo it with the 20y younger desktop :-)

Comment: Yeah, `-march=native` didn't make any difference either.